# Setting a conditional in content.php

Tags: php

I have to put a condition on this function:

```
<div class=imagen01>
<?php sacconicase_post_thumbnail();?>
<div class="mostrasconto"><?php echo ("&nbsp"),"-", get_the_author_meta('discount', $post->post_author ),"%" ;?></div></div>
```

I have to set the following: IF "get_the_author_meta" is empty, dont echo BUT dont show neither the whoole div.mostrasconto. I have to hide this div because there is a background via css

Which is the best solution?

Answer (score 1):

Put an `if` statement around it.

```
<div class=imagen01>
<?php sacconicase_post_thumbnail();?>
<?php 
$discount = get_the_author_meta('discount', $post->post_author );
if !empty($discount) { ?>
    <div class="mostrasconto"><?php echo ("&nbsp"),"-", $discount,"%" ;?></div>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, it broke the site

Comment: Is there an error message?

Comment: Yes, sounds like "permanent error" or "fatal error"

Comment: I figured it out -- the second `</div>` should not be in the `if`

Comment: Maybe I should have specified that one div is in absolute position and the other in relative position, there is one element that goes above the other, as you can see on this page, the discount overlaps with the photos: https://test.sacconicase.com/case-vacanza/italia/toscana/marina-di-massa-appartamenti-vacanze/

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution with the following

```
<div class="imagen01">
<?php sacconicase_post_thumbnail();
$discount = trim( get_the_author_meta ('discount', $post->post_author ));
if ( ! empty( $discount )) {
echo '<div class="mostrasconto">';
echo '&nbsp;-', $discount,'%';
echo '</div>';
}?>
</div>
```

Comment: You're missing the second `</div>`

Comment: you're right, sorry